# Is there a way to remove the trainer models that show in battles in Pokemon Sun?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In Pokémon Sun/Moon when I battle trainers the trainer shows behind the Pokémon that's battling mine. When I was new to the game it didn't matter much but now it's annoying/distracting.

Is there a way to turn it off so you don't see the trainer behind their Pokémon in battles? (I am talking about the opposing trainer in offline battles for all the trainers)

Answer (score 4):

**No**, there's no way to remove the trainer, or for that matter tweak the graphical or model settings at all.

Short of running an emulator and creating a romhack that removes the models, you'll just have to live with it.